# SQL Max function to retrieve one record with related fields in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

In our Query Tool (using ODBC) 4.1
I am trying to get the Max Inv_shipment_date and the corresponding inv_billed_weight, product_ID and division_CD.
I have 4 tables that I have to get the data from (1 has to be used to join the other).
I'm having trouble writing the SQL to get the results down to one line showing the max shipment date.

Tables and the fields needed:

FOS:
Package_key
Inv_Shipment_Date
Inv_Billed_Weight
Division_Key

FIF:
Package_key
Product_key

PD:
Product_key
Product_ID

DD:
Division_Key
Division_CD

End Results I'm hoping for in a table
Max(inv_shipment_date)
Inv_Billed_Weight
Product_ID
Division_CD

What I wrote that is resulting in blank data (I know by looking at the data the max shipment date is actually 20170112, billed weight is 20, division is DOL, and product ID is 03-01984-001)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help smile.gif

```
SELECT 
max(fos.inv_shipment_date_key), 
dd.division_cd, 
pd.product_id,
max(fos.inv_billed_weight)


FROM DCDM.FREIGHT_OUT_SUMMARY fos,
    (select max(inv_shipment_date_key) as Maxinvdate, inv_billed_weight
    from dcdm.freight_out_summary
    group by inv_billed_weight) maxdate,
dcdm.division_dim dd,
dcdm.product_dim pd,
dcdm.freight_invoice_fact fif

where fos.inv_billed_weight = maxdate.inv_billed_weight
and fos.inv_shipment_date_key = maxdate.maxinvdate
and fos.package_key = fif.package_key
and fif.product_key = pd.product_key
and fos.division_key = dd.division_key
and pd.product_id = '03-01984-001'

group by
fos.inv_shipment_date_key, 
dd.division_cd, 
pd.product_id,
fos.inv_billed_weight
```

Comment: Could you share the create scripts of the tables, as well as the insert statements of some sample data?

Comment: max inv_shipment_date_key in whole table, or for a particular set of Division_Key ? Give some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need someone like that. If you remove the `AND` condition at last line, you get the result for all the `product id`. I suggest your remove the last `AND` condition and then run it to see if you are getting desired result. But without sample data, it is really hard to guess.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT Package_key,
          Inv_Billed_Weight,
          Division_Key,
          row_Number() over (partition BY Division_Key
                             ORDER BY Inv_Shipment_Date DESC) AS rn
   FROM DCDM.FREIGHT_OUT_SUMMARY) fos
INNER JOIN dcdm.division_dim dd 
    ON fos.division_key = dd.division_key
INNER JOIN dcdm.freight_invoice_fact fif 
    ON fos.package_key = fif.package_key
INNER JOIN dcdm.product_dim pd 
    ON fif.product_key = pd.product_key
WHERE fos.rn=1
    AND pd.product_id = '03-01984-001'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the MAX shipment date by Product, is that correct? If so, I suggest using a sub-query here initially, and then joining to the other tables (or you can join first but that seems unnecessary). Of course this depends on the identifier you're using - if you have a "shipment ID" that would be ideal.
For example:

```
select
Max(table1.Inv_shipment_date) over (partition by table2.product_ID) as max_shipment_date,
table1.SHIPMENT_ID,
table2.product_Id,
table3.division_Cd,
table4.inv_billed_weight

from
(select
SHIPMENT_ID,
inv_shipment_date

from table 1) as table1

left join
(select
SHIPMENT_ID,
product_ID

from table 2) as table2
on table 1.SHIPMENT_ID = table2.SHIPMENT_ID 

left join
(select
SHIPMENT_ID,
division_Cd

from table 3) as table3
on table 1.SHIPMENT_ID = table3.SHIPMENT_ID

left join
(select
SHIPMENT_ID,
inv_billed_weight

from table 4) as table4
on table 1.SHIPMENT_ID = table4.SHIPMENT_ID
```